# border-bottom for anchor tag on-click css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a sample code with three links.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a.sortType {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.sortLabel {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
 margin-right: 15px;
 }
 
 .sortType {
 margin-right: 15px;
 }
 .sortType:hover{
 border-bottom: 1px solid violet;
 }
 
 a.sortType:active {
 border-bottom: 1px solid violet;
 }

 a.sortType:target {
 border-bottom: 1px solid violet;
 }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div >
<a href="#" class="sortLabel">Sort By:</a>
<a href="#" class="sortType">Date</a>
<a href="#" class="sortType">Place</a>
<a href="#" class="sortType">Name</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I could show the border-bottom line on hover of the option. Now I am trying to maintain the border-bottom line on the selected option. On clicking an option, say 'Date' it should have the bottom-line until I click on other option.
I tried doing it. But couldn't succeed. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use pseudo selector like **active**.

Comment: @UsmanAfzal - The pseudo selector `:active` won't work as you expect in this case, since all links have `href="#"`.

Comment: @AngularDoubts try using java script for that

Comment: You would probably need js for that - 1 to stop the page reloading when you actually put in a href and 2 to fire some sort of ajax request to do your sorting - otherwise use a server side language and check for a get var (if you post back to the same page with a querystring saying which thing to sort)

Answer (score 3):

If your anchor tags aren't necessary, you *could* use radio button inputs and labels together with the [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) pseudo selector and the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) in order to achieve what you're looking for.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a.sortType {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.sortLabel {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
 margin-right: 15px;
 }
 
 .sortType {
 margin-right: 15px;
 }
 .sortType:hover{
 border-bottom: 1px solid violet;
 }
 
 a.sortType:active {
 border-bottom: 1px solid violet;
 }

 a.sortType:target {
 border-bottom: 1px solid violet;
 }

input[type="radio"]{
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + .sortType{
 border-bottom: 1px solid violet;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div >
<a href="#" class="sortLabel">Sort By:</a>

<input id="date" name="sort" value="date" type="radio">
<label for="date" class="sortType">Date</label>

<input id="place" name="sort" value="date" type="radio">
<label for="place" class="sortType">Place</label>

<input id="name" name="sort" value="date" type="radio">
<label for="name" class="sortType">Name</label>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The key CSS that I've added is

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + .sortType{
    border-bottom: 1px solid violet;
}
```

Which styles any `.sortType` element that immediately follows a checked radio input.

Answer (score 1):

Add `:focus`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a.sortType {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.sortLabel {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
 margin-right: 15px;
 }
 
 .sortType {
 margin-right: 15px;
 }
 .sortType:hover{
 border-bottom: 1px solid violet;
 }
 
 a.sortType:active, a.sortType:focus {
 border-bottom: 1px solid violet;
 }

 a.sortType:target {
 border-bottom: 1px solid violet;
 }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div >
<a href="#" class="sortLabel">Sort By:</a>
<a href="#" class="sortType">Date</a>
<a href="#" class="sortType">Place</a>
<a href="#" class="sortType">Name</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `:focus` only works while the element is in focus. If the user clicks on something else on the page (even the body), the style will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//code for styling the active element
var $links = $('a').click(function () {
   $('a').removeClass('clicked');
   $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a.sortType {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.sortLabel {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
 margin-right: 15px;
 }
 
 .sortType {
 margin-right: 15px;
 }
 .sortType:hover{
 border-bottom: 1px solid violet;
 }
 
 a.sortType:active {
 border-bottom: 1px solid violet;
 }

 a.sortType:target {
 border-bottom: 1px solid violet;
 }
 

 .clicked {
  border-bottom: 1px solid violet;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div >
<a href="#" class="sortLabel">Sort By:</a>
<a href="#" class="sortType">Date</a>
<a href="#" class="sortType">Place</a>
<a href="#" class="sortType">Name</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

There are so many approach of doing this, we can use simple jQuery click function to add or remove active class on anchor tag click and style the active class, Hope this solution helps to solve your problem. 
Note: We can add one common class to the anchor tag and target the specific class, in future if there are so many anchor tags, then need to target the anchor tag based on its parent class or specific class.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add basic javascript script for **addClass** when the user clicks on `a`. I just add `active` class. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var all = document.querySelectorAll('.sortType')
  if (e.target.matches('.sortType')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
      all[i].classList.remove('active')
    }
    e.target.classList.add("active");
  }                        
}, false);
```

```css
.reqborder
{
border-bottom:1px solid violet
}
 

a.sortType {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.sortLabel {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
 margin-right: 15px;
 }
 
 .sortType {
 margin-right: 15px;
 }
 .sortType:hover{
 border-bottom: 1px solid violet;
 }
 
 a.sortType.active {
 border-bottom: 1px solid violet;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div >
<a href="#" class="sortLabel">Sort By:</a>
<a href="#" class="sortType">Date</a>
<a href="#" class="sortType">Place</a>
<a href="#" class="sortType">Name</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the anchor tags in li and than apply your styles on the li-items.

A simple navigation menu example from w3schools that you can follow:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;  
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```